# SwiftUI detecting when Preferences/Settings window closes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have preferences view setup like this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        
        #if os(macOS)
        Settings {
            CustomSettingsView()
                .onAppear() {
                    print("this gets called")
                }
                .onDisappear() {
                    print("this is never called")
                }

        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

I want to perform some actions when the preferences window closes.
Is there any way to detect it?

Comment: Your `Settings` view never gets removed from your app. So `onDisapear` will never get called.

Comment: Anyone find an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

Add a completion variable inside to your `CustomSettingsView` like this:

```
struct CustomSettingsView: View {
    var Dismiss:(() -> Void)?

    ...

}
```

Then in your `MyApp` view:

```
CustomSettingsView() {
    print("this now also gets called")
}
    .onAppear() {
        print("this gets called")
    }
```

And finally in your `CustomSettingsView`, call the completion variable in the `.onDisappear` method of your first inner component, eg. a `List` or a `NavigationView`, so your final `CustomSettingsView` struct would look something like this:

```
struct CustomSettingsView: View {
    ...

    NavigationView {

        ...

    }
    .onDisappear {
        Dismiss?()
    }


}
```